# How to add a button to the UITableView's footer view but preserve the last cell separator?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to add a Plus button below the last table cell. It should look like this:

[image]

To get this result I used this code:

```
let footerView = UIView()
tableView.tableFooterView = footerView

addButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 45, height: 45)
addButton.setTitle("+", for: [])
addButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30)

footerView.addSubview(addButton)

addButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addSection), for: .touchUpInside)
```

It looks exactly how I want it but the problem is, as the footer view has a zero frame, the plus button inside it is unresponsive to touch events.

If I set a frame to the footer view:

```
let footerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 45, height: 45))
```

The button starts to respond to touches, but the last cell's separator line is gone:

[image]

Is there a way to add some interactive content to the table footer view but preserve the last separator line?

Comment: That might be  a tough bit. You can try adding a view, like FooterView(sepratorView, yourButton).

Comment: You mean drawing the separator myself? I know I can do it. I just thought there is a more standard solution.

Comment: Also if I use custom separator I will need to handle all logic related to table editing(moving and deleting cells) myself.

Comment: I have the same problem. I'm wondering why when we don't give the size of footerview, the button inside is not responsive to touch event?

Answer (score 0):

Add a line at top of `footerView` like this. Sets the `x` value according to your need.

```
let line = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 1))
line.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
footerView.addSubview(line)
```

Comment: I thought about this but there is some logic(animation) happening with this separator lines when you edit the table. And I don't want to implement it myself.

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable way to do this, is to not use the default separator lines, and rather add it to your cells manually. Simply copy this code to your cell for row just before you return your cell:

```
var separator:UIView!
    if let s = cell.viewWithTag(1000)
    {
        separator = s
    }
    else
    {
        separator = UIView()
        separator.tag = 1000
        separator.backgroundColor = TheColorYouWantForYourSeparator
        separator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cell.addSubview(separator)

        // Swiper constraints
        let leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: separator, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cell, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 15)
        let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: separator, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 0.5)
        let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: separator, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant:0)
        let trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: separator, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 15)
        cell.addConstraints([bottomConstraint, leadingConstraint, heightConstraint, trailingConstraint])
    }
```

This produces a configurable separator view. use the constraints to decide its shape.

Comment: Yes I know I can make the separator view myself but I don't want to. It is not that simple as adding the lines to the bottom of cells. It also involves handling the cases like cell selection, moving and deleting. I believe there should exist simpler solution.

Comment: This solution will not demand any extra handling as you will always want this line. (Remember to disable the separator lines for the tableview) Even if the cell is the last one. Or did I misunderstand your problem?

Comment: No, the standard separators are not always visible.1 - When you select a row, both separators below and above are hidden. 2 - when you move a row in the edit mode the separators of the moved row are hidden but they are presented in the placeholder of the row to where you going to insert the row. Maybe there are other cases..

Comment: I see, then you have a more complex problem, and unfortunately, you will have to manage this manually no matter which solution you choose. Either you must micromanage each cell, or the tableviewFooter when editing.

Comment: I just had a thought... Why not let that button simply be the last cell in the tableview? Only problem then is that it will disappear if there is too many cells. Another thought is that maybe you need to reevaluate your design. You could let the add-button be placed next to the edit-button. If there is no way to solve your problem through code, solve it by design.

Comment: Using tableViewFooter rather than section footer may also look a lot better as it would allow the add button to always stay in the same place regardless of the number of cells in the tableview.

Comment: I have tried to implement the 'add' button as the last cell but then there are also some problems arose related to table editing. For now I decided to put the button outside the tableview.